# How to put expandable listview and linear layout inside scrollview

Tags: android

here is the code am using to display

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/llheadings">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <ExpandableListView
            android:id="@+id/myExpanded"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/llheadings"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
            android:childDivider="@android:color/transparent" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/myExpanded"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

but what happens is ExpandableListView height is wrappeed only item.[and here is the snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nMzSt.png)

if i set hieght(ex:android:layout_height="100dp") then exapandapble listview becomes unscrollable

Comment: You need to use `nestedscrollview` for this purpose..scrollview disabled the inner layout scroll

Comment: ya it works .... but if i set height to expandablelistview as wrap_content, it wraps for only one item and i cant set height explictly because items for expandable listview are dynamically changing

Comment: yes you need to set height manually in dp's.

Comment: is there any alternatives

Comment: yes.assign screen height to your grid view on run time and it will show both views.
`Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
int height = size.y;`
and then set height to your gridview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make `ExpandableListInScrollHelper.java` class for making proper scroll and add below method.

```
public static void getExpandableListViewSize(ExpandableListView myListView) {
    ListAdapter myListAdapter = myListView.getAdapter();
    if (myListAdapter == null) {
        //do nothing return null
        return;
    }
    //set listAdapter in loop for getting final size
    int totalHeight = 0;
    for (int size = 0; size < myListAdapter.getCount(); size++) {
        View listItem = myListAdapter.getView(size, null, myListView);
        listItem.measure(0, 0);
        totalHeight += listItem.getMeasuredHeight();
    }
    //setting listview item in adapter
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = myListView.getLayoutParams();
    params.height = totalHeight + (myListView.getDividerHeight() * (myListAdapter.getCount() - 1));
    myListView.setLayoutParams(params);
    // print height of adapter on log
    Log.i("height of listItem:", String.valueOf(totalHeight));
}
```

Now, add one line of code below set adaptor like

```
mExpandableList.setAdapter(mAdapter);
ExpandableListInScrollHelper.getExpandableListViewSize(mExpandableList);
```

And now your problem is solved!!!